# Google Analytics Pie Chart widget filters not working

Tags: android, google-analytics, widget, pie-chart, dashboard

I'm trying to use Google Analytics to show a Pie Chart on my dashboard that uses the data from a couple of `Event Actions` and `Screen Name` sent from my Android app. Basically I would like to track how many times a button in a particular screen (Fragment) is being clicked (the button performs an action which could either succeed or fail), and also see if it failed or succeeded.

The screen is tracked with a `setScreenName()` and `HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build();` and the button click event and subsequent result events (pass/fail) are tracked with `HitBuilders().EventBuilder().setCategory().setAction().setLabel().build();`

Now in my Analytics dashboard, I tried adding 3 filters, one for the screen name, the 2nd for the pass event action, and the 3rd for the fail event action. However the widget displays a "There is no data for this view". The only way I get the Pie Chart to show anything is to use only one filter which defeats the purpose of having a Pie Chart.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how I can use multiple event actions and screen names to show up on the same Pie Chart widget in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 2):

The first criteria is to select `Create a pie chart showing` and `grouped by` options in GA pie chart widget and then filter results. Since you get results by selecting any one filter: screen name/ success event / failed event, I suppose the results are present in the first criteria.

You can then filter results by a `Don't show` or `Only show` option. A failed and success event cannot appear together, so probably you should not apply filter for both of them at the same time.

Also I think you cannot attach a screen name to event 
[Google Analytics screenname for events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414559/google-analytics-screenname-for-events) so don't think you can have a screen name + success / fail event filter either.

[image]